# urllib.parse.urlparse not reading params

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to read parameters in python

```
 urlparse('jdbc:mysql:@localhost:3306/mysql;user:pass?jdbc_driver_name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) params are placed after semicolon, but I'm getting empty string for params in my example url.

Comment: For those looking for the right format for which url parsing works, once you set it to this format: "mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/mysql?jdbc_driver_name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driverr" you can access username like obj.username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code:

```
uses_params = ['', 'ftp', 'hdl', 'prospero', 'http', 'imap',
               'https', 'shttp', 'rtsp', 'rtspu', 'sip', 'sips',
               'mms', 'sftp', 'tel']
```

It only parses params if thee scheme in this list.

```
def urlparse(url, scheme='', allow_fragments=True):
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
    splitresult = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
    scheme, netloc, url, query, fragment = splitresult
    if scheme in uses_params and ';' in url: # <------------------------------ Right here
        url, params = _splitparams(url)
    else:
        params = ''
    result = ParseResult(scheme, netloc, url, params, query, fragment)
    return _coerce_result(result)
```

Comment: And from the documentation: "It supports the following URL schemes: file, ftp, gopher, hdl, http, https, imap, mailto, mms, news, nntp, prospero, rsync, rtsp, rtspu, sftp, shttp, sip, sips, snews, svn, svn+ssh, telnet, wais, ws, wss." So apparently 'jdbc' is not supported.